# Building libcurl for Android in Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, curl, android-ndk

I am trying to find build instructions for building libcurl for Android in either Windows or Ubuntu. I have found a lot of links on the topic, but all those date few years back and do not seem to work as such with recent NDK versions.

However, I found this recently updated gitlab project: https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios

But trying to build it according to readme instructions leads to following error:

....
jni/../../openssl/bio_ssl.c:63:10: fatal error: 'opensll/crypto.h' file not found

crypto.h is in the opensll/crypto/ folder. In general it seems that header file locations are wrong all over the openssl sourcefiles. So what is the right way to solve this, some makefile setting or env variable?

Here is the full build output:

```
perza@perza-Ubuntu64:~/AndroidStudioProjects/cURL/curl-android-ios/curl-compile-scripts$ ./build_Android.sh Configuring for android
no-asm          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_ASM
no-camellia     [option]   OPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA (skip dir)
no-cast         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_CAST (skip dir)
no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
no-idea         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_IDEA (skip dir)
no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
no-shared       [option]  
no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
no-ssl2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
no-whirpool     [option]   OPENSSL_NO_WHIRPOOL (skip dir)
no-zlib         [default] 
no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -mandroid -I$(ANDROID_DEV)/include -B$(ANDROID_DEV)/lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
EX_LIBS       =-ldl
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o
BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
DES_UNROLL used
DES_INT used
BN_LLONG mode
RC4 uses uchar
RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long
BF_PTR used
sh: 1: make: not found
make: Entering directory `/home/perza/AndroidStudioProjects/cURL/curl-android-ios/curl-compile-scripts'
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : ssl <= bio_ssl.c
jni/../../openssl/ssl/bio_ssl.c:63:10: fatal error: 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ssl/__/__/openssl/ssl/bio_ssl.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/perza/AndroidStudioProjects/cURL/curl-android-ios/curl-compile-scripts'
Error building the libssl and libcrypto
perza@perza-Ubuntu64:~/AndroidStudioProjects/cURL/curl-android-ios/curl-compile-scripts$
```

br, perza

Comment: Weird. I see `curl-android-ios/openssl/ssl/bio_ssl.c`, with no **jni/**. Did you not forget to `cd curl-compile-scripts` as in instructions?

Comment: No I did not. I added the full build output to original question, just in case.

Comment: `sh: 1: make: not found` may be enough to cause troubles. Please try to fix your path. **make** can be found in your NDK.

Comment: Good spot! The error line caught my eyes completely. Will check that.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem. Damn I be blind sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your **automake** found that **make** was not on the `PATH` rather late. Note that **make** executable is available in **NDK** bundle, so you only need to set the `PATH` variable correctly.